# How to access CC uploaded files in Lightroom Web?

Tags: lightroom, creative-cloud

##### Question:

Please let me know if there is a workaround for the **Issue** below, or if another workflow is advised.  This is my first post in Photography and I'm happy to be here!

##### Issue:

Lightroom Web is not aware of any assets, though they have been uploaded already via CC Synced Files.

##### Steps to reproduce:

1. log in to a new CC account (mine is a 10yr institutional license)
2. upload some NEF photos to `Creative Cloud -> Files -> Synced Files -> folder name` (see **Evidence** below).
3. navigate to https://lightroom.adobe.com.
4. notice that Lightroom Web is unaware of any existing assets and prompts the user to upload some files (see **Evidence** below)

##### Evidence:

###### *Some files I uploaded today*:

[image: synced files]

###### *Lightroom Web (showing no assets)*:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adobe Creative Cloud cloud storage is different from Lightroom. You should install Lightroom CC on your computer and upload the files and then after they sync they will appear on Lightroom Web.